Replicate tables from read-only SQL Server instance to local SQL Server
I have read-only access to a Microsoft SQL Server 2022 instance - that is, one database within the instance that I have permissions to connect to with SSMS and run queries against - and I would like to routinely (once a day would suffice) copy a handful of tables (or really a subset of the data therein, using dates to limit the results) to a local SQL Server which I have full control over.
The local SQL Server would act as a data warehouse of sorts which I use for SSRS and Power BI.
Before I go down the path of using SSIS to import .csv files every day, is there an easier way? I don't believe linked servers are an option for me due to permissions.

PolyBase? OPENROWSET? EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE + EXTERNAL TABLE?

You can absolutely create a linked server on your local comp against the read only remote server, although i fail to see why you need to copy data, why not just use SSRS or whatever against it directly

@siggemannen SSMS's UX when connected to a SQL Server instance over a high-latency connection is still atrocious (especially the Object Explorer and the whole UI freezing for a half-second any time you right-click anything) - so that's a valid reason for me.

@siggemannen Well that's superb - I'm probably just undercaffeinated, but I had it in my head that I needed to do something on both ends of a linked server setup... I've only set one up a couple of times ever. Thank you!

Have you seen this page - it explains and compares the main options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-openquery-openrowset-exec-at?view=sql-server-ver16

As others have said, a linked server should work fine but if you find performance is poor then you could use SSIS as you suggested. I'm not sure why you would need CSV files though, a simple transfer of data directly between the servers, direct to your local target tables would be the easier and faster way to do it.
